# Translation report field "Primary address?"

Tags: translation

When you choose a report, i.e. Constituent Summary you have the Column "Primary Address?" 
That can not be translated because is it not in any po-file. 
There is "Primary Address". 
In CRM/Report/Form.php : ts('Primary Address?')

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This should be available for translating in transifex now as per the recent announcement in the chat translation channel. This was updated today: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/blob/bb10330a29b701e898dd41ff062e6dd53075f512/po/pot/report.pot#L2162

---

It looks like that was only fixed in the code about 5 months ago (see [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/1836ab9ebef1a2924241bc5fc0f86812628b17cc#diff-d355cdb00cea3915a3cf306c6c08f6a6R5774)) so may not have moved into transifex yet. I'm not sure what the schedule is.

Probably the best place to ask language questions is at https://chat.civicrm.org in the Translation channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i did my post on the wrong site. I used the last time, some time ago, the old site with jira, and this site is more for questions than for issues.
For issues the right site wil be: lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues  (gitlab)